# Lazy Loading an array of images fails to update to the next image in the array

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement lazy loading on my personal project. I have been able to make it work on my homepage, or my gallery page, but never both.

I believe the issue is that "lowResImage" is not updating it's path to the next item in the array.

I apologize if this code is poorly written, I am just beginning to learn, and I've moved things around a lot trying to find a solution.

```
// SET RES-IMAGE-REPLACEMENT, AND RUN LAZYLOADERSETUP ON EACH IMAGE
resImageReplacements = document.getElementsByClassName('res-image-replacement');

for (let i = 0; i < resImageReplacements.length; i++) {
  lazyLoaderSetup(resImageReplacements[i], i);
}



function lazyLoaderSetup(i) {
  highResImage = document.createElement("IMG");
  lowResImage = document.getElementsByClassName('picturesToBeSwapped')[i];
  resReplacement = document.getElementsByClassName("res-image-replacement")[i];

  // SET HIGH RES IMAGE UP WITH CLASS, ID, AND HIGH RES SOURCE
  highResImage.setAttribute("class", "mainBackground");
  highResImage.setAttribute("id", "mainBackground");
  highResImage.setAttribute('src', lowResImage.getAttribute("high-res-src"));

  // IF THE LOW RES IMAGE CLASS EXISTS, ADD THE LOAD LISTENER WHICH WILL RUN REMOVEAPPEND FUNCTION
  if (resReplacement.contains(lowResImage)) {
    highResImage.addEventListener('load', removeAppend);
  }
}




// REMOVE THE LOW RES ELEMENT, ADD THE HIGH RES ELEMENT, REMOVE LISTENER
function removeAppend() {
  resReplacement.removeChild(lowResImage);
  resReplacement.appendChild(highResImage);
  highResImage.removeEventListener('load', removeAppend);
}
```

Comment: `lazyLoaderSetup()` takes `i` as argument, you are passing both `resImageReplacements[i]` and `i` to it.

Comment: Okay, I will try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the Lazy Loader to function correctly. Setting `lowResImage` to always be the first element in the `picturesToBeSwapped` array fixed my issue. Here is my updated code, hopefully it can be helpful to someone in the future.

```
// SET RES-IMAGE-REPLACEMENT, AND RUN LAZYLOADERSETUP ON EACH IMAGE
resImageReplacements = document.getElementsByClassName('res-image-replacement');

for (let i = 0; i < resImageReplacements.length; i++) {
     lazyLoaderSetup(i);

}



function lazyLoaderSetup( i) {
  highResImage = document.createElement("IMG");
  lowResImage = document.getElementsByClassName('picturesToBeSwapped')[0];
  resReplacement = document.getElementsByClassName("res-image-replacement")[i];

  // SET HIGH RES IMAGE UP WITH CLASS, ID, AND HIGH RES SOURCE
  highResImage.setAttribute("class", "mainBackground");
  highResImage.setAttribute('src', lowResImage.getAttribute("high-res-src"));

  // IF THE LOW RES IMAGE CLASS EXISTS, ADD THE LOAD LISTENER WHICH WILL RUN REMOVEAPPEND FUNCTION
  if (resReplacement.contains(lowResImage)) {
    highResImage.addEventListener('load', removeAppend);
  }
}




// REMOVE THE LOW RES ELEMENT, ADD THE HIGH RES ELEMENT, REMOVE LISTENER
function removeAppend() {
  resReplacement.removeChild(lowResImage);
  resReplacement.appendChild(highResImage);
  highResImage.removeEventListener('load', removeAppend());

}
```